# Algorithm to print the Minimum number of adjacent character swaps necessary to remove all instances of "VK" in a given string?

Tags: code-golf, string, programming-puzzle, recursion

For example, how many adjacent swaps are at least needed to convert some string such as `BVVKCV` to one without any instances of `VK`?

Input-length of the string will be within the range `1 <= length <= 200`.
`VK` will be hardcoded across all test cases.

Input string examples:

```
Input:  VKVKVVVKVOVKVQKKKVVK
Output: 8

Input:  VVKEVKK
Output: 3

Input:  JUSTIN
Output: 0
```

Comment: I've formatted your post a bit. As mentioned by @JoKing above, is the `"vk"` hard-coded, or given as second input? Also, you will need a [winning criteria tag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/52210). `[code-golf]` is the most common one to use.

Comment: The "VK" is hard coded.

Comment: Lowercase `vk` or uppercase? Also, I'd recommend rewriting the title to something less "I need help with my homework" sounding

Comment: I would appreciate some more test cases =D

Comment: `bvvkcv` does not contain any instances of `VK`. Perhaps a test case like `VKVKVKVK`?

Comment: Suggested test case: `KV => 0`

Comment: This question seems really unclear... so I'm making character swaps to position Vs in front of Ks, so they can be removed as an ordered pair? Will I always have an equal number, or might I end up with extra Vs or Ks? Must I make *all* the swaps before removing *anything*? Or can I remove each `VK` as it appears, which reduces the number of letters in the way for remaining swaps?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Shouldn't that be 1?

Comment: @BradC My reading of the challenge is that the original string is only reordered using swaps until "VK" is not a substring of it. Characters are never removed. "VK" is not a substring of "KV" so no swaps are necessary.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Ohhh, that kind of makes sense? Still very unclearly worded.

Comment: Substring or subsequence? Should 'VXK' return 0 or 2?

Comment: @user202729 it should return 0

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 44 bytes

```
m£Z¯Y cZtY2 Ô cZsY+2Ãrc
®¬ø"VK"
W+VÌ
Ve ?ß:W
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=baNar1kgY1p0WTIg1CBjWnNZKzLDcmMKrqz4IlZLIgpXK1bMClZlID/fOlc=&input=W1siViIsIlYiLCJLIiwiRSIsIlYiLCJLIiwiSyJdXQotUQ==)

It times out on the first test case because it's super inefficient (something like O(n^n)?) but it should be a viable algorithm. Input is weird; it is a [singleton list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/71434) containing the input, but the input itself is formatted as a list of upper-case characters. I think that would typically be valid, but if not let me know.

Explanation:

```
#Step 1: try all the swaps
m                          #For each string Z reachable with n swaps (n starts at 0)
 £                  Ã      # For each letter Y in Z:
  Z¯Y                      #  Get the letters before it in Z
      c                    #  Concat
       ZtY2 Ô              #  Y swapped with the following character
              c            #  Concat
               ZsY+2       #  The rest of Z
                     rc    #Flatten by one level
                           #Result: A list of all strings reachable with n+1 swaps

#Step 2: Check for "VK"
®¬         #For each string from Step 1:
  ø"VK"    # Check whether it contains "VK"
           #Result: A list where 1 indicates there was "VK" and 0 otherwise

#Step 3: Increment the counter appropriately
W+      #Increase the counter by
  VÌ    #The value for the original string when run through step 2
        #Result: 0 if 0 swaps were required, the current number of swaps otherwise

#Step 4: Iterate or end
Ve ?       #If all the reachable strings contain "VK"
    ß      # Repeat the program with the current values
     :W    #Otherwise return the counter
           #Result: Outputs the counter when a non-"VK" string is found.
```

Comment: A couple of quick savings to get you down to [44 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=baNar1kgY1p0WTIg1CBjWnNZKzLDcmMKrqz4IlZLIgpXK1bMClZlID/fOlc=&input=W1siViIsIlYiLCJLIiwiRSIsIlYiLCJLIiwiSyJdXQotUQ==).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes

```python
s={input()}
a=0
while all("VK"in q for q in s):a+=1;s={a[:i]+a[i+1]+a[i]+a[i+2:]for a in s for i in range(len(a)-1)}
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9i2OjOvoLREQ7OWK9HWgKs8IzMnVSExJ0dDKcxbKTNPoVAhLb8ISAKZxZpWidq2htZAPYnRVpmx2onRmdqGYArCNrKKBSlOBCsG68sEMYsS89JTNXJS8zQSNXUNgRYVFGXmlQA5//@HeQNhGBD7A3GgtzeQ4w0A)

Basic BFS.